# AJAX Error: Connection refused?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I'm running a Digital Ocean server here on a MEN stack (MongoDB, Express, and Node), with a registration form:
http://45.55.177.167:3000/register

If you try to select an option from the dropdown, I'm getting the following error:
`GET http://45.55.177.167:3000/price?name=pro&cycle=monthly net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

I'm wondering why this is? I would like for the error to go away and get the response back so that the price changes accordingly.

My AJAX method:

```
$.get('/price', parameters, function(data) {
    callback(data.price);
});
```

The Route:
`app.route('/price').get(plans.getPrice);`

The Controller:

```
var param_name = req.query.name;
var param_cycle = req.query.cycle;

var query = param_name + "_" + param_cycle;

Plan.findByName(query, function(err, selected_plan) {
    var formatted_price = format_price(selected_plan.price) + '.00';
    res.send({price: formatted_price});
});
```

This is working fine on my localhost, but when I deploy it to a droplet, I'm getting the error. Please let me know if clarification is needed.

Comment: Need to open port 3000 on your droplet's iptables, probably.

Comment: I  just checked the ip you listed (**be careful about that, just fyi**) and got a connection refused error. It's almost certainly port or host isn't allowed in the droplet's iptables. This is not an issue with your code. If you need help getting started, maybe take a look at this (one of the many excellent DO walkthroughs) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-using-iptables-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I will look into this and post a reply if this solved my issue.

Comment: Sorry! ^^ Thank you for this. I looked into it and I'm still confused. I will be taking this to a server admin, who I'm hoping can further explain this to me. Once I figure out what's wrong, I will post my results as an answer!

Comment: I can post the steps as an answer if you tell me what flavor *nix your droplet is.

Comment: I did a 1-click MEAN install droplet. But I'm not 100% familiar with grunt, so I don't have my grunt set up to do grunt. I'm currently doing `node server` ~ a step by step idea of what to do would be great, as this is a little over my head ~ thank you so much. ^-^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78132/discussion-between-satyrwilder-and-lindsay).

Comment: I've created a chat for us to go through this.

Comment: I saw, but it seems you've already left. I'm still having this issue. Could it be because my mongo database does not have a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking your ip, I determined that your problem was data. You were getting the error "refused connection" because the app didn't have any sanity tests on the expected object parameters it was operating on. Without data, trying to access properties that were undefined was throwing errors, causing your app to break without and return the error you saw in the client.

We didn't change any of your code to resolve this issue. Your project can be considered done.

Migrating your data from your local mongo db collections to your remote host resolved the issue. As I demonstrated, there is a simple fix for quickly migrating simple data structures over: connect to mongo on the command line, select your database, and `find()` each of your collections. As you noticed, they are simply JSON objects that can be copy-pasta'd to the new remote destination's `insert()` statement with minimal modification.

*This isn't an advisable solution for situations with more data than simply structured, limited data in a handful of collections; you'd want to use a **programmatic solution** such as dumping the db for anything larger than we were working with here.*